# Can I pass a member function of a class as a function parameter?

Tags: c++, function, member

So I have a function in C++ which takes in another function:

```
double integral(double (*f)(double x){...};
```

I also have a class which has a member function f:

```
 class Test{
 public:
     double myfun(double x){...};
 };
```

I want to be able to call the integral function using the member function myfun of class Test. Is there a way to do this? For example, is it possible to do the following:

```
 Test A;
 integral(A.myfun);
```

I would even like to take this further and call integral within class Test, using its own member function as input!

Thanks!

Comment: I've never needed to and am not sure you can. I do this for static functions, but for regular member functions I arrange things to use polymorphism or function objects.

Comment: Is your `integral` function your own? Can you make modifications to it, to accept other types?

Comment: In this example, yes it is. But for the real problem, this function is not something I can easily change.

Answer (score 2):

No; an ordinary function pointer cannot store the address to a non-static member function. Here are two solutions you might consider.

1) Make `myfun` static. Then `integral(A::myfun)` should compile.

2) If you have C++11 support, make the `integral` function take a general functor type,

```
template<typename Functor>
double integral(Functor f) { ... };
```

and bind an instance of `Test` to create a function object that only takes a `double` as an argument,

```
Test A;
integral(std::bind(&Test::myfun, A, std::placeholders::_1));
```

or simply pass a lambda,

```
Test A;
integral([&A](double x){ return A.myfun(x); });
```

Comment: You can use the boost libraries and get boost::bind if you don't have c++11 support.